# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oledb

```
    public void RegisterUser(string passw,string uname ,string fname ,string lname, string email)
{
    string strSql = @"INSERT INTO User (passw,uname,fname,lname,email) values ('" + passw + "','" + uname + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "')";                                                           
    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql,cn);
    int yy= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    cn.Dispose();

}
```

**no matter what i do i get the same error**
does anyone see here something wrong?
or there is another creative way to solve this problem
thanks

Comment: Use parameterized commands, it's more secure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and print the contents of the query string?

Answer (score 6):

Your code here can change dynamically depending on the user input. And that is what causing the error.

Let me explain if any of your input fields contain an apostroph [ ' ] the sql breaks and has now an unclosed quote.

Not only that it also exposes your code to **SQL-Injection Attacks**.

so i suggest you use **parameters** for passing value as parameters are treated differenty and are safe as well as prevent SQL-Injection.

```
    public void RegisterUser(string passw,string uname ,string fname ,string lname, string email)
{
    string strSql = @"INSERT INTO User (passw,uname,fname,lname,email) values     (@passw,@uname,@fname,@lname,@email)";                                                           
    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql,cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passw",passw);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",uname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname",fname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname",lname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",email);
    int yy= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    cn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. just to inform you that If it realy helped then you can  accept the answer by ticking the (right) symbol on the left side of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `user` is a reserved word and `INSERT INTO User ...` generates `ORA-00903: invalid table name`.